# DataTable rows aren't turning into hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables, href

I created a table with DataTables and at first the document titles that were rendered (from a local JSON file) were wrapped around anchor tags and turned into hrefs. I made some changes to my DataTable initialization and added some new columns to my table, and those things might have prevented the doc titles from turning into hrefs. I'm not 100% sure.

#### Importing table data:

```
loadTableData() {
  $.noConflict();

  let tableRes = KMdocs.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
    return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
  }).map(function(obj) {
    return {
      "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
      "Titles": obj.File.Name,
      "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
        return val.Label;
      }).join(";"),
      "Blank": ""
    }
  });
}
```

#### Rendering table:

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable({
  columns: [
    { data: "Blank" },
    {
      data: "Titles",
      columnDefs: [ // ----- I believe the issue is with this block
        {
          data: "Path",
          ordering: true,
          targets: [ 1 ],
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
                .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
                .text(data)
                .wrap('<div></div>')
                .parent()
                .html();
          },
          targets: [1]
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      data: "Categories",
      searchable: true,
      targets: [ 2 ],
      visible: false
    },
    {
      data: "Blank"
    }
  ],
  data: tableRes,
  language: { searchPlaceholder: "Search All Documents" },
  lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500 ],
  order: [],
  pageLength: 500,
  paging: true,
  pagingType: "full_numbers",
  responsive: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  scrollXInner: true,
  scrollY: 550,
  sDom: '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"left">' // puts dropdown on bottom
});
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<table id="km-table-id" class="cell-border display stripe-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Categories</th>
      <th>My Favorites</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody></tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try removing the newly added columns one by one till the issue disappeared?

Comment: I did, but unfortunately nothing happened.

Comment: Create a working snippet of your code and I'll look into it